# How to redirect user to home page after successful login in php?

Tags: php

When I go to homepage.php, I would redirected to login.php and when I entered my login details and press submit, I am being directed to homepage.php.  However, when I go to login.php, I am not automatically being brought to homepage.php despite being logged in.

login.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include("global.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);
    $userid = $_POST['txtLogin'];
    $password = $_POST['txtPassword'];

    $query = "SELECT userid from users where userid ='$userid' and password = '".md5($password)."'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 1) {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = '$userid' ; { 
            header("Location: homepage.php");
            exit(); 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

homepage.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { 
    header("Location: login.php"); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a condition in your login page whether `$_SESSION['login_user']` is set or not.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include("global.php");
session_start();

// before going further, first check whether session is active or not.
// if it is active then redirect user to homepage.php otherwise
// proceed further
if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { 
    header("Location: homepage.php"); 
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);
    $userid = $_POST['txtLogin'];
    $password = $_POST['txtPassword'];

    $query = "SELECT userid from users where userid ='$userid' and password = '".md5($password)."'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 1) {
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = '$userid' ; { 
            header("Location: homepage.php");
            exit(); 
        }
    }
}
?>
```