# logged in but not staying on the same page when refresh

Tags: php, session

When I am on homepage.php and  I press refresh, I am automatically brought back to login.php despite it not being 30 minutes yet. May I know what went wrong

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset( $_SESSION['login_user'] )  && (time() - $_SESSION['login_user'] > 1800)) { // 30 minutes
session_unset();
session_destroy();
} else if (!isset( $_SESSION['login_user'] ) ) { 
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code never sets `$_SESSION['login_user']`

Comment: [Your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52827838/1415724) where you used sessions, is using `$_SESSION['login_user']` as the session array, why are you using a new one here; new project? Enable error reporting and you'll get your answer. Btw, in that other question, you did `$_SESSION['login_user'] = '$userid' ;` - that variable in single quotes, will not work, since it's in single quotes. Variables don't get parsed in those; they should just be removed. Another thing; it's completely unsafe; MD5 shouldn't be trusted.

Comment: Parse your time date_parse(time())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code snippet you have pasted here, your variable `$_SESSION['login_user']` is never set:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset( $_SESSION['login_user'] )  && (time() - $_SESSION['login_user'] > 1800)) { // 30 minutes
session_unset();
session_destroy();
} else if (!isset( $_SESSION['login_user'] ) ) { 
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit(); 
}
?>
```

You can have it working by assigning a value to it, in this case `time()`. Try adding this line in your code after verifying `$_SESSION['login_user']` is not set:

`$_SESSION['login_user'] = time();`

That way you can actually check when user has previously logged in and compare it with last 30 minutes as in:

`time() - $_SESSION['login_user'] > 1800`

You would have something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset( $_SESSION['login_user'] )  && (time() - $_SESSION['login_user'] > 1800)) { // 30 minutes
session_unset();
session_destroy();
} else if (!isset( $_SESSION['login_user'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = time(); // <-- New line added
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes - while you're right about the policy it also brushes up against putting too much superfluous language in the answer. To be kind is to provide an answer or comment without talking "down" to the OP. You need not go out of your way to greet them and welcome them here as a good answer, explained well, provides the right message without having to add to it. You did a great job of that with your answer.